# Grails 2.2 not recognizing homepage view

Tags: grails, upgrade, gsp

I'm upgrading a grails 1.3.6 app to 2.2.4.  In 1.3.6, the app is accessed by hitting `localhost:8080/APPNAME`.  This then renders the file in `grails-app/views/index.gsp`.

After upgrading the app to 2.2.4, hitting `localhost:8080/APPNAME'` returns an error of :

`HTTP Status 404 - "/index.gsp" not found.`.

My URLMappings file is as follows:

```
class UrlMappings 
{

static mappings = 
{
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }

    "/"(view:"/index")
    //"500"(view:'/error')
    "500"(controller: 'pacErrors', action: 'handleErrors')
}
}
```

I am able to access controllers directly via URL calls, so the server does appear to be up and running.

Comment: For the sake of others who see this problem when deploying a WAR file: It may help to run "grails run-war", and then look at the log files for additional information.

Answer (score 0):

It all seems correct, sometimes when confronted with weird behaviours after an upgrade, I find the best fix is a "grails clean", and make sure that the app is indeed migrated to 2.2.4 by running "grails upgrade".

If this does not work, try creating a new application directly with grails 2.2.4 to test it out. If you cannot spot the problem after that, you could copy your existing app into the new one.